# Raise error, v # invalid expression when trying to create azure nic interface via az cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to create Network interface on Azure using AZ Cli command and it is showing following error.
Ansible modules for the same have some hard requirements of urllib3 and requests package hence trying to use Azure cli.
The stacktrace looks like its a module issue.

````
/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

nothing to repeat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 523, in execute
    self.commands_loader.load_arguments(command)
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 291, in load_arguments
    self.command_table[command].load_arguments()  # this loads the arguments via reflection
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 290, in load_arguments
    super(AzCliCommand, self).load_arguments()
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 97, in load_arguments
    cmd_args = self.arguments_loader()
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 488, in default_arguments_loader
    op = handler or self.get_op_handler(operation, operation_group=kwargs.get('operation_group'))
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 528, in get_op_handler
    op = import_module(mod_to_import)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/network/custom.py", line 23, in <module>
    from azure.cli.command_modules.network.zone_file.parse_zone_file import parse_zone_file
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/network/zone_file/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from azure.cli.command_modules.network.zone_file.parse_zone_file import parse_zone_file
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/network/zone_file/parse_zone_file.py", line 77, in <module>
    _COMPILED_REGEX = {k: re.compile(v, re.IGNORECASE) for k, v in _REGEX.items()}
  File "/root/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/network/zone_file/parse_zone_file.py", line 77, in <dictcomp>
    _COMPILED_REGEX = {k: re.compile(v, re.IGNORECASE) for k, v in _REGEX.items()}
  File "/root/bin/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/root/bin/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat```

Following packages I am using for az cli :
azure-cli                             2.0.71                  
azure-cli-command-modules-nspkg       2.0.3                   
azure-cli-core                        2.0.35                  
azure-cli-nspkg                       3.0.2                   
azure-cli-telemetry                   1.0.3
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems your python version need to be upgraded, could you please upgrade your python to 2.7.7